# Building Expressions for QGIS Markers

Tags: qgis, style, expression, markers

I have a tab delimited text file with a column "Status". It can have values OFF-AIR or ON-AIR. How do I control the marker properties like colour or out-line using the expression building. I am not looking for categorized symbol, I need the expression.
This is my syntax, but it is not working:

```
CASE WHEN  "STATUS"  = 'ON AIR' THEN  color_rgba(255,255,0,80)
  WHEN  "STATUS"  = 'OFF AIR' THEN  color_rgba(255,0,0,80)
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't come across this issue before but it seems to work if you use three single quotation marks for the values:

```
CASE WHEN "STATUS" = '''ON AIR''' THEN color_rgba(255,255,0,80) 
WHEN "STATUS" = '''OFF AIR''' THEN color_rgba(255,0,0,80) 
END
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @Joseph: can you explain why you need 3 single quotation marks here?  This is so different from the other expressions where values only needs 1.

Comment: Hmm you shouldn't need need more then one ` because that is a string.

Comment: @Arindam - Most welcome, glad it worked :)

Comment: @PieterB - You need 3 single quotation marks if the values in the csv file already contain single quotation marks which I guessed what the OP did.

Comment: @NathanW - You're right, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Joseph, that make sense :-)