# QGIS Marker Expressions

Tags: qgis, markers, syntax

I am working on writing basic expressions to control the Marker Properties. My previous question on the syntax for color was graciously answered , but I soon realized that I need to know the syntax for all the properties like , size, outline, angle. Is there a place I can find them all[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your previous question ([Building Expressions for QGIS Markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206650/building-expressions-for-qgis-markers)) you have to click on **Data defined override** button and choose **Description...**, there are information about possible values and and wich value type is acceptable. String values in syntax have to be in simple quotes like *'my_value'*.

1.
[image]

2.

[image]

For your previous example - expression changing *Fill style*:

```
CASE WHEN "STATUS" = 'ON AIR' THEN 'b_diagonal' 
WHEN "STATUS" = 'OFF AIR' THEN 'f_diagonal'
END
```